# How to compare the features and performance of JuliaDB and Queryverse? Which is better?

Tags: package, julia

It is observed there are a few feature overlapping amongst packages.
 
Please guide me in comparing features and  performance of JuliaDB and Queryverse and deciding the better one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JuliaDB.jl and Queryverse operate on different layers of abstraction.

Queryverse provides tools for manipulation and visualization of various data sources and does not provide data source layer itself.

JuliaDB.jl, on the other hand, provides a specific data source implementation, that is particularly valuable when working with very large data sets that do not fit into RAM and are processed in distributed manner. The closest alternative to JuliaDB.jl is DataFrames.jl package. A brief comparison of both is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495318/are-juliadb-or-dataframe-faster-than-plain-array), so you can see that each has its uses in different contexts. Queryverse works "on top" of any of these sources.

You might also want to have a look at [Tables.jl](https://github.com/JuliaData/Tables.jl) package that defines a low-level API for tabular data. In particular even `NamedTuple` of vectors and a vector of `NamedTuples` can be considered as tabular data.

One thing you should keep in mind when working with Queryverse is that for type inference reasons it defines its own notion of missingness in in [DataValues.jl](https://github.com/queryverse/DataValues.jl) package that is not the same as `Missing` type defined in Base.